# Setting up a Google hosted account to Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I've gotten a school mandated Gmail account running on Google hosted, which I'd like to set up with Thunderbird.

The instructions assume a gmail domain rather than the domain google apps is running on - do I use `username@school.edu` as my username and `school.edu` as my server or `gmail.com` as my server, or some other combination?  The rest of the settings are clear to me, but that bit seems to have tripped me up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do i use username@school.edu as my username

Yes.

> school.edu as my server or gmail.com as my server,

The domain remains gmail.com, not your domain.

As [the support article](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77654) mentions:

> Configuring IMAP access for your Google Apps email address is very similar to configuring it in Gmail. However, any time you're asked for your username during the configuration process, you'll need to enter your full email address, including your domain (username@your_domain.com). All other settings are the same.